# Send custom adb command to recovery

Tags: android, shell, adb, recovery, platform-tools

I'm trying to communicate with a recovery via adb. The recovery is proprietary, made by Xiaomi. When using `adb devices` command, the device in recovery mode is recognized as "sideload" so there is no way to open a shell or whatever. However, a special version of adb (also made by xiaomi) can send special commands to communicate, such as `adb getsn` or `adb getversion`. This commands are not available in google's platform tools, they return help screen if you try them.

Now my issue: the recovery has been updated and it has new commands that I discovered by looking at the strings in the binary file of recovery (such as "getromzone"), but if I try `adb getromzone` I get the help screen because Xiaomi's adb has not been updated with new commands and doesn't recognize them. How can I send this new commands to the recovery? Thank you. Sorry for bad English.